# How to set GridView item size by largest item

Tags: gridview, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to display multiple items in a `GridView`. It was picked mostly for its horizontal scroll behavior.

It looks like `GridView` defines item size based on the 1st item dimensions. In the code example below, longer month names are cropped if the year starts on January, but if the first item is wider, the names are displayed as intended.

I do want to keep `GridView` having all items of the same width, but that must be the width of the largest one. Same goes for height, but in my case the height is constant.

Is there a relatively easy way to achieve this with a `GridView`, or maybe there is a more suitable control for this?

---

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.Items>
        <x:String>January</x:String>
        <x:String>February</x:String>
        <x:String>...</x:String>
        <x:String>September</x:String>
        <x:String>October</x:String>
        <x:String>November</x:String>
        <x:String>December</x:String>
    </GridView.Items>
</GridView>
```

[image: GridView output]

N.B. There are multiple examples for different/variable item size out there. Unfortunately, that's *not* what required.

Comment: You could create a custom `GridView` class (just inherits from the base `GridView`) which overrides `ArrangeOverride`. When it is arranging the items, first it measures *all* of them (not one at a time) and selects the item size based on the largest of the items.

Comment: @Nate Diamond thank you, but could you elaborate 1-2 steps further? The reason I ask is that re-arranging items during a call to `ArrangeOverride` would cause a recursive layout update with almost guaranteed exception. Besides it might make sense customizing `ItemsPanel` container instead of the `GridView` if I go that direction.

Comment: I don't necessarily mean re-arranging them. ArrangeOverride should call arrange on each sub-item, passing in the amount of space that item is going to be given. So that means that it should be able to search the `Measure` values of the items (instead of just using the first item) and finding the largest of them. It's true that this may be done with a `Panel` instead, such as making a custom `VariableSizeWrapGrid`.

Comment: Well, `ArrangeOverride` takes `finalSize` of the control; unless I miss something, there is no info on how `GridView` would position individual items: at that point `GridView` is a black box if you talk about derived class. I've got your idea though, thanks. It makes sense, but it still requires more steps to work. At the moment, I'm using a workaround along the same lines: inherit `GridView`, run `Measure()` on all the items at some point before the calls to `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`, get max of `DesiredSize`, expose it as a DP and bind item's MinWidth, MinHeight to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, the easiest way to satisfy the requirements was with a custom panel in the `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

A couple of rejected approaches was
1) Extending `GridView`: while a developer has access to lots of interesting information when derived from the GridView, the actual layout management is performed in `GridView.ItemsPanel` control and modifying items position outside of it calls for a number of hacks or fragile design decisions.
2) Extending existing `ItemPanel` containers: this would be the most natural approach, but since classes like `WrapGrid` or `VariableSizedWrapGrid` are sealed, that's not possible.

Here's an example of using a custom panel with a `GridView`.
Alignment settings position items in the top-left corner instead of the center if there are too few items to fill in the entire `GridView`.
Margin is compensating for the default behavior of the scroll bars to overlap the content.

```
<GridView ... >
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <controls:GridViewPanel
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="0,0,0,24" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    ...
</GridView>
```

A full custom panel code is below. It is intentionally simplistic, but it can be easily extended  for specific additional requirements like more precise layout control, variable column width, virtualization etc. It wasn't tested though with more advanced `GridView` features like grouping.

```
using System;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

/// <summary>
/// Uniformly positions child items in columns to present in WrapGrid.
/// Uses largest item's DesiredSize for item size mesasurements.
/// Expects limited height and unbound width.
/// </summary>
public class GridViewPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        return ArrangeInternal(availableSize, callArrange: false);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        return ArrangeInternal(finalSize);
    }

    private Size ArrangeInternal(Size size, bool callArrange = true)
    {
        // measure max desired item size
        //
        double itemWidth = 0.0, itemHeight = 0.0;
        foreach (var item in Children)
        {
            item.Measure(size);
            itemWidth = Math.Max(itemWidth, item.DesiredSize.Width);
            itemHeight = Math.Max(itemHeight, item.DesiredSize.Height);
        }
        // requested item height can't exceed total available height
        itemHeight = Math.Min(itemHeight, size.Height);

        // position each child and get total content size
        //
        double totalWidth = 0.0, totalHeight = 0.0;
        double x = 0.0, y = 0.0;

        foreach (var item in Children)
        {
            if (y + itemHeight > size.Height)
            {
                // if item won't fit, move to the next column
                totalHeight = Math.Max(totalHeight, y);
                y = 0;
                x += itemWidth;
            }

            // implicitly, item fits in current column
            if (callArrange) item.Arrange(new Rect(x, y, itemWidth, itemHeight));
            y += itemHeight;
        }

        totalWidth = x + itemWidth;
        totalHeight = Math.Max(totalHeight, y);

        return new Size(totalWidth, totalHeight);
    }
}
```